# How to send post request from c# windows forms to a laravel api with files?

Tags: c#, laravel, api

I have a windows form that will send a post request to my simple laravel api.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
    private async void UploadScreenshot(string employee_id, string filepath)
    {

        string url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload-screenshot";
     
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var multiForm = new MultipartFormDataContent();


            Image ssimage = Image.FromFile(filepath);
            var byteimg = ImageToByteArray(ssimage);
            ByteArrayContent screenshotimg = new ByteArrayContent(byteimg);


            multiForm.Add(new ByteArrayContent(byteimg), "files");
            multiForm.Add(new StringContent(employee_id), "emp_number");


            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, multiForm);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(responseString);
            //Console.WriteLine(responseString);

        }
    }
```

this code is working only for `StringContent`.but in my `ByteArrayContent` it returns null. Event using the `MultipartFormDataContent`. I tried every answer here in Stackoverflow since yesterday but no luck for me.

this is my Laravel API controller:

```
public function UploadScreenshot(Request $request){

    $emp_number = $request->emp_number; //this is working..
    $file = $request->files; //this is null

    if ($request->hasFile('screenshot')) {
        $file = request()->file('files');

        $fname = date('YmdHis');

        $ext = $request->files->extension();

        $filename = $fname . '.' . $ext;
       

        $file->storeAs('screenshots/', $filename, ['disk' => 'private']);

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did and works like a charm:

On PrintScreen method, I first save the file to temp dir. Then call my `UploadScreenshot()` method,

```
    private void PrintScreen()
    {
        DateTime utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        string filename = emp_number + " - " + utc.Ticks.ToString() + ".png";

        Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);

        graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);

        printscreen.Save(runnitsettings + filename, ImageFormat.Png);

        UploadScreenshot(emp_number, runnitsettings + filename);
    }
```

In this function, I retrieve the file from the directory and load it to `FileStream`, instead of adding the file directly to a `MultipartFormDataContent();` I created a function `ImageToByte()` that will first convert the file to `byte` and then convert to `Base64String`.

```
    private void UploadScreenshot(string employee_id, string filepath)
    {

        string url = baseurl + "upload-screenshot";


        System.IO.FileStream fsstream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
        string b64image = ImageToByte(fsstream);
        fsstream.Dispose();
        File.Delete(filepath);

        //I deleted the file after convertion to free some diskspace.

        var multiForm = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        multiForm.Add(new StringContent(employee_id), "emp_number");
        multiForm.Add(new StringContent(b64image), "files");


        //Then I post the data:
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, multiForm);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

Image to Byte Function:

```
    public static string ImageToByte(FileStream fs)
    {
        byte[] imgBytes = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(imgBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        string encodeData = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);

        return encodeData;
    }
```

In My Laravel Controller, I handle the file like this:

```
        $destinationpath = config('filesystems.disks')["private"]["root"]."/screenshots"."/";
        $emp_number = $request["emp_number"];
        $screenshot = $request["files"];
        
        $filename = $emp_number.'-'.date('YmdHis');

        $filePath = $destinationpath.$filename.".png";

        file_put_contents($filePath, base64_decode($screenshot));
```